# admin/config page taking around 30 seconds to load; the rest of the website loads fast

Tags: performance

I have a new Drupal install and it works allright, everything loads fast, except for the Configuration page at admin/config. What I have done so far to try to tackle the problem:
- Disabled all contrib modules, with no success.
- Disabled the Update Manager module, no success either.
- Enabled Devel and extended query logs, besides page execution time: ordinary pages take some 300 ms to load. The admin/config page is taking around 30000 ms to load. There is no evidence in the logs that it has to do with the database queries. On the Config page, none of them is above the threshold limit.

It then occurred to me trying something else: I am inside a corporate network and there are two different ways to enter this Drupal site: by checking the internal IP false address and by checking the external IP address the IT team has set for this server (open to the world).

I found that by navigating to the Configuration page from the internal IP address, there is no delay at all, the page loads fast! By navigating into it from the external IP address, the page gets these 30 seconds delays to load.

Any ideas on how I should try to fix this issue with the IT team? I have access to the server and I can run commands on the command line and maybe check server logs. I am not a Linux specialist, but I can follow instructions and run commands.

Comment: In the net panel of your browser it should break down what is taking the longest, DNS, time to first byte, ect. Knowing that will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I could narrow down the issue to one specific wi-fi network where this issue is happening (my office wi-fi network, but one that is used by guests). I will try to monitor with the browser tools. Anyway, not a Drupal issue. I am just curious about what could be causing all this delay specifically in admin/config page. If I find out, I will post it here.

Comment: When connecting to the network again on another day, I didn`t experience any more problems with the slow admin/config page: it is coming fast now, the same way as the other pages. So I guess I won't have an answer to this question. The issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The admin/config page can trigger a check of the site 'status report' which depending on the modules & services your site uses may check for the ability to connect to certain services. 30 seconds sounds like it is trying to use some service but throws a timeout after 30 seconds. Try checking the status report under working / not-working conditions to see if some services are being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if your watchdog table is very large. Going into the mysql backend and doing

`truncate watchdog;`

solved this problem for me.

The watchdog table contains logs, so truncating it is safe in that it will not affect the working of the system.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, Naomi. This is an old post and I don't even remember the project which was experiencing the issue described in this post. I think it was a project running in a local environment. Anyway, I will 'store' this solution in my mind as a possible solution in case I ever come accross such problems again. Thank you for sharing!